# Navicat access for Heroku database

Tags: heroku, navicat

I'm having troubling accessing a free Heroku database (Dev plan) through Navicat.

When I connect I can see a long list of databases, much like here http://twitter.com/bazscott/status/290780256221147136, but I cannot find my particular database in the list, neither can I connect to any of the others.

Is this because I'm using a free database plan, and only paid plans allow Navicat access?

PS. I have no problem accessing my database through **heroku pg:psql**.

Comment: Can you not specify the specific database for your connection in Navicat?

Comment: I just dropped the database from heroku and created a new one again, and then it works, however my pg:info looks a bit odd still with Data Size: 0 B eventhough I can see there's data..

Comment: The stats on databases are collected by a background worker, so they aren't "live" stats.